# Python Dictionary not allowing to subtract the values from each other (not keys, values)

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

I have python dictionaries inside a list:

```
list_with_dicts = [
  {"01/1/2021": 35},
  {"01/2/2020": 36},
  {"01/2/2021": 33}
]
```

I want to add another value part into each dictionary that says the first value minus the second value. For example, 35 - 36, but there one important part. The numbers that you minus from each other have to be in the format of one is above the others. Finally, I need the data to be stored to a csv file.

Comment: invalid syntax of your dict key.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean

Comment: these dates should be string, otherwise you get syntax error

Comment: and tell us how the output you want to look like

Comment: I'm struggling to understand this "I want to add another value part into each dictionary that says the first value minus the second value." Can you give us an example?

Comment: I meant that I need  another value part in the dictionary that shows the numbers subtracted from each other

Comment: With what key? The values substracted from which dictionaries and put as a value where? Is this just for the first and second dicts, or do you want all pairs? Give a **concrete** output based on the example you've already provided with your dicts.